# Cant parse multi-array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to parse this array in order to save it in the database, but I can't do it.

This is what `$this->input->post("question")` produces:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => question 1
            [answer] => Array
                (
                    [0] => answer 1
                    [1] => answer 2
                    [2] => answer 3
                    [3] => asnwer 4
                    [4] => answeer 5
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => queston 2
            [answer] => Array
                (
                    [0] => answer 21
                    [1] => answere 22
                    [2] => anwer 23
                    [3] => answer 24
                    [4] => answer 25
                )

        )

)
```

I tried this:

```
foreach ($this->input->post("question") as $questions) {
            foreach ($questions as $question) { 
                $data = array(
                    'question' => $question,
                );
                $this->db->insert('questions', $data);
                $question_id = $this->db->insert_id();
//another foreach to go throw answers

           }
}
```

Just to check if I save the questions correctly, but I am getting this message:

> Message:  Array to string conversion

Comment: who is who in that array? who is `$this->input->post("question")` ?

Comment: @AresDraguna $this->input->post("question") produce the array printed

Comment: then who is `$exam_id`?

Comment: @AresDraguna dont care about it, I updated my code

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are getting that message because you are trying to convert an array to a string.

Second:

```
foreach ($this->input->post("question") as $questions) {

}
```

first level. After this, you remain with:

```
[1] => Array
(
   [0] => question 1
   [answer] => Array
    (
       [0] => answer 1
       [1] => answer 2
       [2] => answer 3
       [3] => asnwer 4
       [4] => answeer 5
    )

)

foreach ($this->input->post("question") as $questions) {
    foreach ($questions as $question) { 
        //here, $question is formed of 2 arrays
        //[0] => question 1 
        //[answer] => Array
        //  (
        //     [0] => answer 1
        //     [1] => answer 2
        //     [2] => answer 3
        //     [3] => asnwer 4
        //     [4] => answeer 5
        //  )

    }       
}
```

that is the second level. so in that foreach, you should use:

```
$data = array(
   'question' => $question[0], // to get the question string
);
```

Let me know if anything more is needed!

**P.S:** for answers, you have to go one level deeper, and make another foreach.